# faMapMarker not visualized properly

Tags: fontawesome, icon

I am having problems visualizing properly some of the `fontawesome` icons, for example, my `\faMapMarker` looks big, ugly, and without a hole in the middle.

This is a sample code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}

\faMapMarker\ Location, Country

\end{document}
```

And this is the resulting icon:
[image]

But I want it to look like this: [image]

I have tried to switch to `fontawesome5` but no luck there either. I have also noticed that other icons also look a bit off and I presume it is from the font but I have tried with other fonts without any success.

Comment: As the package name `fontawesome5` indicates, it gives symbols of Font Awesome 5. Their [`map-marker` symbol](https://fontawesome.com/icons/map-marker?style=solid) looks exactly like the icon you get, but they also have a [`map-marker-alt` icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/map-marker-alt?style=solid) which has a hole. (In the LaTeX package available with `\faMapMarker*`) If you don't like that either you can try the old `fontawesome` package which gives you the Font Awesome 4.6 icons instead.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger that's strange, because I have tried with both packages: `fontawesome` and `fontawesome5` and got exactly the same result, but I am using Overleaf, so maybe there is a problem and even if you define `fontawesome` you get the icons from v.5

Comment: I did some tests in Overleaf and confirmed that everything works as expected: You get Font Awesome 4 symbols with `fontawesome` and Font Awesome 5 symbols with `fontawesome5`.